# Java Modulus 1 (%1) returns approximate value

Tags: java, modulus

I've got sample code

```
double k=3.14, l=0.5, m=1.3333;
        System.out.println(k+":"+k%1);
        System.out.println(l+":"+l%1);
        System.out.println(m+":"+m%1);
```

which results in output:

```
3.14:0.14000000000000012
0.5:0.5
1.3333:0.33329999999999993
```

Why is it so? I expected x%1 to return non-integer part of the value of x?

Comment: Floating point values aren't precise. Rounding errors always need to be accounted for after any operation.

Comment: `0.14` and `0.3333` can't be represented exactly, that's why there are rounding errors. `0.5` on the other hand can be represented exactly.

Comment: http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/showfloat.php?floatvalue=3.14&floattype=double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

> Binary floating point math is like this. In most programming languages, it is based on the IEEE 754 standard. JavaScript uses 64-bit floating point representation, which is the same as Java's double. The crux of the problem is that numbers are represented in this format as a whole number times a power of two; rational numbers (such as 0.1, which is 1/10) whose denominator is not a power of two cannot be exactly represented.